# Unexpected result of StrComp when using vbTextCompare

Tags: vba, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

### The goal

Compare two strings lexicographically, ignoring case.

### Possible solutions using StrComp

Consider the following script:

```
val1 = "test9999"
val2 = "TEST_59895"

LexCompare val1, val2, vbBinaryCompare
LexCompare LCase(val1), LCase(val2), vbBinaryCompare
LexCompare UCase(val1), UCase(val2), vbBinaryCompare

LexCompare val1, val2, vbTextCompare
LexCompare LCase(val1), LCase(val2), vbTextCompare
LexCompare UCase(val1), UCase(val2), vbTextCompare

WScript.Echo "ANSI values: '9'=" & Asc("9") & ", '_'=" & Asc("_")

Sub LexCompare(string1, string2, compareType)
    result = ""
    Select Case StrComp(string1, string2, compareType)
        Case -1
            result = "is smaller than"
        Case 0
            result = "is identical to"
        Case 1
            result = "is greater than"
    End Select
    WScript.Echo "'" & string1 & "' " & result & " '" & string2 & "', compareType: " & compareType
End Sub
```

Output:

```
'test9999' is greater than 'TEST_59895', compareType: 0
'test9999' is smaller than 'test_59895', compareType: 0
'TEST9999' is smaller than 'TEST_59895', compareType: 0
'test9999' is greater than 'TEST_59895', compareType: 1
'test9999' is greater than 'test_59895', compareType: 1
'TEST9999' is greater than 'TEST_59895', compareType: 1
ANSI values: '9'=57, '_'=95
```

To me, "test9999" should be lexicographically smaller than "TEST_59895", ignoring case. Why? Because '9' is smaller than '_'.

### Questions

- What am I missing?
- I understand the results when using `vbBinaryCompare` and will use either `LCase`-ing or `UCase`-ing both variables as a workaround.
- But why doesn't `StrComp` come to the same conclusion using `vbTextCompare`? I thought the very definition of `vbTextCompare` was to compare ignoring case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect of `vbTextCompare` is applying the rules of `Option Compare Text` to just that one comparison.

You can see in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/8t3khw5f(v=vs.80).aspx) that `Option Compare Text` does not rely on ANSI values, rather it relies on

> case-insensitive text sort order determined by your system's locale.

Your locale can dictate any sort order, so it happens to [sort digits after underscores](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/18/134051.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I should drop the "VBS" from my queries more often. However, I couldn't find how _exactly_ (on the character level) the locale influences the sort order. Are there any resources that could shed some light on this?

Comment: @BenjaminThiel The point is that it shouldn't bother you exactly how it happens - the system sorts strings in a way that would "feel natural" to the user when they look at a sorted list, and the rules for doing so may be quite complicated. If you want fine control on what is sorted where, you probably should implement your own comparison function.

Comment: As for the documentation, you can start at [`CompareString` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317759.aspx) and follow the links e.g. to [Handling Sorting in Your Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318144.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't bother if it weren't my task to _test_ if certain values are ordered ascendingly/descendingly. Not having access to the code of the application I'm testing makes it even more complicated...